Opening in the door frame

Hi,
I'm seeing a slight opening in the door frame.
Is there any sealant or so that I could apply?
Or
Is a structural issue with the frame?

Just looks like the caulking is opening up a bit.  Best idea is to remove all old caulking, clean and replace with a paintable caulking.

Yep, probably opened up as the wood dried out and shrank.
